# Building portable shop, light bulbs burning out

Tags: electrical

So I am building a coffee shop that is on a trailer, it runs off of a 220v plug that I connect to my house or other locations. When I connect it to my outlet my light bulbs inside are blowing out. I have a breaker box in the trailer, and I need the 220 volts to run the espresso. What could be causing the light bulbs to be blowing out. I’m using fluorescent bulbs. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. What country are you in? Are your light fixtures also 220VAC? If not, how do you get 120VAC from 220VAC?

Comment: How many prongs are on the plug?  Does this happen anywhere else, or just your house?

Comment: You have a fixture with a creaky old magnetic (transformer based) ballast.  Change the fluorescent ballasts to a modern electronic type that accepts 240V.  Most modern ballasts happily input anything from 120 to 277 volts, and auto-adjust, no need to set switches or jumpers.   They definitely won't blow out!